# Changing CSS flex-direction changes standard width

Tags: html, css

I have two containers stated in html as below

```css
.flex-group {
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 40%;
}

.any-container {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
}

.any-container2 {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  transform: translateX(40%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-group">
  <div class="any-container"></div>
  <div class="any-container2"></div>
</div>
```

the default width of .flex-group if I put flex-direction: row is zero but when I set it again to column the default width is something greater than 0 (the element becomes visible with no content) why does it happen? what is the name of this behavior?

I wouldn't like to make .flex-group visible when flex-direction: row but just to know why default width is not zero as it does to column? Is it a css bug? do we just go css randomly until all things are ok in frontend? or is it really logic and formal?

Comment: Hiya! I think you can improve this question by removing the following portion:

"Is it a css bug? do we just go css randomly until all things are ok in frontend? or is it really logic and formal?"

Generally speaking, this kind of put down targeting a language and community makes it less likely you'll get the help you want.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the behavior you want, where the .flex-group is not visible when flex-direction is set to row, you can explicitly set the width to 0 when flex-direction is row. You can use a conditional class or some JavaScript to apply different styles based on the flex-direction. For example:

```css
.flex-group {
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 40%;
    width: 0;
}

.flex-group.column {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: auto;
}
```

Then, in your HTML or JavaScript, you can add or remove the column class based on your requirements. This way, you have more control over the appearance of the .flex-group container.